# iOS7 status bar state during a phone call

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, statusbar

In iOS 5/6 I was observing status bar frame changes and I adopted UI according to that. This was needed when phone call was in progress (in such cases status bar was bigger).

Now in iOS7 status bar is transparent by default, and when phone call is in progress it becomes green. In landscape orientation it changes only opacity.

How can I be notified that status bar status changes (is transparent or not) and how can I check what is current state of its transparency?

In `UIApplicationbDelegate` I don't see any new notification about this status bar state change. I see only:

```
– application:willChangeStatusBarOrientation:duration:
– application:didChangeStatusBarOrientation:
– application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:
– application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:
```

Currently my UI behaves perfectly, only in landscape orientation this is a problem since my content is hidden under status bar and I'd like to fix it (I have scroll area there so I'm planing to add top content inset depending on status bar state)

Comment: Shouldn't you have that content inset all the time, to avoid your scrollView overlapping the status bar text?

Comment: Yes it would be some solution, but I'm not sure UX designer will like it.

Comment: In iOS 7 there are many inbuilt features to keep the content from drawing under the status / navigation bar. Calculating the height of the status bar is absolutely not the way to achieve this. You probably need to look at `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` and read the iOS 7 tutorials

Comment: Did you ever find anything additional about this problem? It's crushing me at the moment, thanks to landscape orientation: in landscape, the change status bar frame methods aren't called when the call-in-progress green bar comes on or off, since only the color changes there.

Comment: no progress at all. I was occupied by other more important tasks. Probably final outcome will be that I will use @michaels proposal.